# while loop never ends and I can't figure out how to stop it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I have an assignment, everything is going smoothly, but when I input a certain value into the loop it never stops, unlike other values that I input, which is odd and I can't figure out how to deal with it.
Here is the code:

```
dim = int(input())
pos = int(input())
v = int(input())
vi = v
a = int(input())
posa = dim +1

print(pos)
while v != 0 or v*vi>0:
    if -dim < pos < dim or pos == dim or pos == -dim:
        pos += v
    elif pos > dim:
        pos = dim
        v -= a
        v = -v
    elif pos < -dim:
        pos = -dim
        v += a
        v = -v
    if -dim <= pos <= dim and not posa==pos:
        print(pos)
        posa = pos
```

For some context, it's a program that is meant to give the position of a bumper car, dim and -dim are the walls the car can crash into and then bounce back, pos is the starting position, v is the initial velocity and a is by how much the absolute value of the value lowers once bumps into a wall. It is supposed to stop eventually once there is no more velocity.
The problem is that if the input is 10,-3,6,2; it works perfectly, but if its input is 10,-3,8,3; the loop never ends, and I can't figure out why.

EDIT: I can't use for, def, import, break, continue, and lists and similar things, basically just the most basic stuff like if and while.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? Did you try checking what the value is for each variable, at the beginning of the loop? Did you try tracing through the logic by hand?

Comment: What in the code ensures that v will ever equal zero?  For example, if v==1 and a==2, you may bump v back and forth between -1 and 1, but never reaching zero.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if -dim < pos < dim or pos == dim or pos == -dim:
        pos += v
```

```
    if -dim <= pos <= dim and not posa==pos:
        print(pos)
        posa = pos
```

those  blocks has no operation for `v`, its value never changed, looping forever.

Comment: The point is for `pos` to change so that eventually `if -dim < pos < dim or pos == dim or pos == -dim` fails, allowing either `elif pos > dim:` or `elif pos < -dim:`, whereupon `v` can change.